# Why Unity object Destructor calls before the object was created?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have my object in Unity and this object has a destructor as well as `Awake` method

```
...
    private void Awake()
    {
        Debug.Log("AWAKE");
    }

    ~UnityHumanObject()
    {
        Debug.Log("DESTRUCTOR");
        if (stream != null)
        {
            stream_release(stream);
        }
    }
...
```

when I click on `Run` button according to the log I see that destructor prints his log message 3 times and just after that I see `Awake` log message... Next, if I click stop (Run button again), I don't see that destructor even get a call.

So, question is - why when I click on run button first of all I get 3 time call to destructor and secondly why if I stop Unity I don't actually get destructor call?

Comment: Because when you enter playmode the current scene is unloaded from editor mode and then loaded in playmode. You should have **no constructors** and **no deconstructed** for `MonoBehaviour` or any other built-in type of Unity! Rather use `OnDestroy` as mentioned below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to implement a receiver for `OnDestroy()` instead.
See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDestroy.html

I don't know the full ins and outs of how Unity engine works, but I can tell you that things that derive from `UnityEngine.Object` (which includes MonoBehaviors) are a hybrid type that is part managed-code and part unmanaged-code.  The Editor is also an arcane beast in that it runs your scene as you're editing it, but restricts certain Messages/calls until you're in "play" mode (or register with the ExecuteInEditor attribute).

With all of that, it becomes quite impossible to manage your code using low-level constructors and destructors if you're extending any of the Unity classes.  Simply put, don't do it unless the Unity-specific functionality doesn't support what you need.  In your case, closing a stream, using an `OnDestroy()` function should be perfectly sufficient.

Comment: Just to add: The deconstructor is called because when entering Playmode the scene is basically reloaded so that all `Awake` and `Start` calls are done. So basically every currently existing instance in the edit mode scene is deconstructed first => **Never** implement constructors or destructors for anything inheriting from the Unity built-in types .. rather use `OnDestroy` as correctly mentioned here